# 2 columns in a row, percentage width

Tags: html, css, percentage

I have a problem on arrange the 2 columns in a row.
The 1st column in 2% width, and the 2nd column in 98% width.
How can I make them work?
I have try float:left; but it seems not a proper way to do it.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/gWGvxG

```
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div>
  <div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>

.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inline-block` count blank space as a content, that's why it not set in 100% width. to set these element you can use following method

```css
.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div><!--
  --><div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

**or**

```css
.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div>
  <div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

**or**

```css
.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div>
  <div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div>
  <div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:flex` you can easily achieve this. In your code there was a problem so **I will suggest you to use this approach**. Also `word-break:break-all` to **adjust the text** in the `2% div` as its width is probably small.

```css
.moonsun {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.moon {
  width: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
  word-break: break-all
}

.sun {
  width: 98%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="moonsun">
  <div class="moon">Moon<br><br></div>
  <div class="sun">Sun<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```